# Minimal python script renders nothing without any error

Tags: python

Does anybody see why I'm not getting any image rendered?

```
# /tmp/blender/blender_mini_example.py
import bpy
import time
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = str(int(time.time())) + '.render' + '.png'
# Add a cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(-3, 0, 0))
# Render
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filename
# Print directory path and filename
print(dir_path+"/"+filename)
```

---

```
cd /tmp/blender
sudo prime-run blender --background --python blender_mini_example.py --verbose -1
echo "Count of png in $(pwd): $(ls *.png | wc -l)"
```

---

```
------------------Load-----------------
/tmp/blender/1628351080.render.png
Blender 2.93.2 (hash 1eb06de2607a built 2021-08-04 15:17:57)
Read prefs: /root/.config/blender/2.93/config/userpref.blend

Blender quit
Count of png in /tmp/blender: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it: `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` was missing after `bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filename`